# Assign a returned array from a function to a variable in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble assigning a character array returned from a function to a variable in main.

```
char *read(char filename[]) {
    int i = 0;
    am = 0;
    char line[80];
    char *record[100];
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, infile) != NULL) {
        record[i] = strdup(line);
        i++;
        am++;
    }
    return record;
}
...

int main() {
    char input[100];
    char *record[100];
    char input2[100];
    char input3[100];
    while (1) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &input);
        strcpy(input2, strtok(input, " "));
        if (strcmp(input2, "print") == 0){
            print(record);

        ...

        else if (strcmp(input2, "read") == 0) {
            strcpy(input3, strtok(NULL, " "));
            record = read(input3); //input3 is the file name
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to take the character array given by "read" and pass it to "print", but I've been unsuccessful. There will be no erroneous input.

Edit: I've tried dynamically allocating, but I'm still not getting what I want. Did I do it incorrectly?

```
char* read(char filename[]) {
    int i = 0;
    am = 0;
    char line[80];
    char *record = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    if (record == NULL) return NULL;
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, infile) != NULL) {
        printf(line);
        record[i] = strdup(line);
        i++;
        am++;
    }
    return record;
}
```

Comment: What does "There will be no erroneous input" mean? The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

Comment: `record` is a stack variable, so once the function `return`s the address to it, it is no longer valid and should not be used.

Comment: The function does not return a character array.

Comment: What does your compiler have to say about your code?

Comment: You have multiple problems here.  For one, you can't return a pointer to local storage, since that storage is no longer available upon return from the function.  For another, even if you could, the data types are incompatible:  `record` has type `char *[100]`, i.e. an array of `char` pointers, while the function is declared to return a `char *`, i.e. a single `char` pointer.  So you need to make up your mind about what you want to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the variable `record`, declared as `char * record[100];`.

When you declare the `[100]`, you are creating storage on the stack. Stack storage is only valid while the function that contains it is still in scope. (For example, you could pass `record` down to a different function called from within `read()`.)

So when `read()` returns record, it is returning a pointer to the start of the array. But the array itself is no longer valid, since `read()` - the function that contained `record` - is no longer in scope.

You can solve this problem by creating a file-scope storage (a variable at file scope) version of `record`; or by using *dynamic allocation* (e.g., `malloc` or `calloc`) to create the storage for `record` on the heap; or by passing the storage for `record` in to `read()` from `main()`.

The generally accepted way to do this is to use *dynamic allocation* to create heap storage, and then return that. Please be aware that if you do that, you step into the realm of *ownership semantics* - you have to decide who owns the storage, and who will release the storage you allocate.

Please also be aware that `strdup()` itself uses dynamic memory allocation to make a copy of your buffer. You are already doing some of this, even if you don't realize it. :-)

Comment: I edited my code, but it still seems wrong--also, if I am able to write read() correctly, would my main function be correct?

Comment: You now have the wrong type for `record.` You can't just remove the [100] and pretend it's the same. Try changing it to `char **record` (note the two stars) and initialize it with `= calloc(100, sizeof(char *))` (note char *). At that point, you have a block of char* objects, which can then hold the pointers you will get back from `strdup`.

Comment: Your main appears to be missing a closing brace for the while. But you have elided a bunch of stuff, so maybe not. My recommendation would be to write a simple `main` that just calls `read` on a known filename and prints out the result. Use that until you know that `read` works, then go on to the next command.